# I catch a lot of errors when i start my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react project is very simple, it has only few lines of JSX and everything else is default

```
> pp@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './base64-vlq'
Require stack:
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/source-map-js/source-map.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parse.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js
- /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js:8:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/source-map-js/lib/source-map-generator.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/source-map-js/source-map.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/map-generator.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/postcss-safe-parser/lib/safe-parse.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js',
    '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
```

Also when i tried to install prop-types i got more errors:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/abab
npm ERR! dest /home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/.abab-KaEQmoPw
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/abab' -> '/home/arjun/Documents/pizdec/pp/node_modules/.abab-KaEQmoPw'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/arjun/.npm/_logs/2021-07-07T14_03_35_405Z-debug.log
```

I tried to reinstall npm and nodejs but nothing change, also i tried to restart computer but result is the same.
I use Arch linux
And here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "pp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you installed that module? that 'base64' one?

Comment: Yes, it was working for a first few minutes, but i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the code in prop-types.

`import ./base64-vlq` => `import ./base64-vlq/index`